# How to import images from a folder and set part of them as testing data and part of them as training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to import all 60,000 images (50,000 for training and 10,000 for testing) inside a directory (the directory location is known) in Python for image classification using TensorFlow. I want to import all images and let them

`path = /home/user/mydirectory`

I try code:

```
import numpy as np                                               
import keras                                                     
from keras.models import Sequential                              
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten     
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D                    
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator         
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                  
from keras.utils import np_utils          

from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob(r'/home/user/mydirectory*.gif'): #assuming gif
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
(x_train, y_train)=image_list()
(x_test, y_test)=image_list()
```

However, the error is `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to call the list as a function which is throwing the error.
I think the below code can help you to get two subsets for your data.

```
import numpy as np
import random                                        
import keras                                                     
from keras.models import Sequential                              
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten     
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D                    
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator         
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                  
from keras.utils import np_utils          

from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob(r'/home/user/mydirectory*.gif'): #assuming gif
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)

random.shuffle(image_list) # This line now has shuffled your list(inplace operation)
n = len(image_list)
train_data_len = int(n*0.83) # Roughly 50k images
train_data = images_list[:train_data_len] # getting images upto 50k index
test_data = images[train_data_len:] # getting rest of the images
```

There are other ways to process the data. Found this an easy one to begin with.

Comment: How about I have two different directories? One is for training and another one is for testing?

Comment: Here is error based on your code: `NameError: name 'random' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
... = image_list
```

in the last 2 lines above instead of

```
... = image_list()
```

as it is a list, not a callable function.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling list `image_list()` in the last and second last line. You are trying to split into train and label, but you don't have a category added to `image_list`.

You can create a folder with a category name; for example, suppose you have
two classes, dog and cat, then you can create training directory like:

```
home/usr/mydirectory/train/cat
home/usr/mydirectory/train/dog
```

and use Image Data Generator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)
training_set =train_datagen.flow_from_directory(  
                                            'home/usr/mydirectory/train/',
                                             target_size = (64, 64),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')
```

Similarly, for test data, you can create a directory with test and store images with the category as the folder name.

Comment: Thanks! How about if I have 10 classes rather than 2?

Comment: you can make 10 different directories, or you can create a CSV file in which the first column contains the image name and the second column  contains the label

Comment: Can you write a code about how to create a CSV file? Thanks!

Comment: But for a training data set. I did not know the label for each image. How to label them?

Comment: Without label, how will you train your classifier? What do you want to classify?